# Unable to get search result in mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, search-engine

I'm a new user here and having a problem with my search result. I'm currently build a website with a search for posts feature. It work fine with mysql. And then I read about PHP will remove some of old feature. So i tried to convert from mysql to mysqli but I got lot of error. I don't know what else to do because I've tried lot of suggestions from here and google but it still won't work. There are only 2 fields `(title, keywords)` in my table `(search_table)`. Result I need is `'title'` will appear if user search for any `'keywords'`.

My form:

```
<form name="search_form" action="search.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="search_posts" placeholder="Search for posts" size="20" maxlength="50"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

My working mysql:

```
<?php
$host='localhost';
$mysql_username='root';
$mysql_password='';
$database='my_db';
$connection_error='<b>Unable to connect to the database!</b>';
if(!@mysql_connect( $host , $mysql_username , $mysql_password ) || !@mysql_select_db($database))
{
die ($connection_error);
}

$search = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['search_posts']));
$find_posts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `search_table` WHERE `keywords` LIKE '%$search%'") ;
$count = mysql_num_rows($find_posts);
if($count == 0){
    echo 'There are no search result!';
} else {
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_posts))
{
    $title = $row['title'];
    $keywords = $row['keywords'];
    echo "<a href='#'>$title</a> >>> $keywords<br />";
}
}
?>
```

Converted mysqli (problem):

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$mysql_username = 'root';
$mysql_password = '';
$my_database = 'my_db';
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$mysql_username,$mysql_password,$my_database);
if($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connection to database failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit(); 
}

$search_posts = $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['search_posts']));
$find_posts = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `search_table` WHERE `keywords`='?'") or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

if($count == 0) {
echo 'NO SEARCH RESULTS FOUND!';
}
else {
while($row = $find_posts->fetch_assoc())
{
    $title = $row['title'];
    $keywords = $row['keywords'];
    echo "<a href='#'>$title</a> >>> $keywords<br />";
}
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

P/S : Sorry for my bad english. I hope you guys can help me or explain to me in simple way since I'm don't have much knowledge in this field (self taught-try & error stuff ^_^). I will appreciate if you guys have better solution as long as it will work as the old one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kinds of errors were you getting when you switched?

Comment: Now, I'm actually not familiar with mysqli (I'm more a PDO-kinda guy). However, You don't seem to be passing in any keywords to your query, and that'll be problematic. In addition, when using parameterized queries, you don't need the single quotes around the question mark.

Comment: lot of error like undefined num_rows, undefined $title etc. I cant remember because it changed everytime i try to change mysqli code.

Comment: In addition, if you want to use parameters, you need to first [prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) the statement, which will mean a few additional lines of code. Check that link out, as well as [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php) regarding the mysqli-stmt object returned by a preparation.

Comment: @ChrisForrence I've tried that. But it give me an error about prepare. Probably i didnt do it right. So i remove it.

Comment: @Shah - Ok, we can work with that. What was the specific error? Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22068806/edit) your post to add any/all error messages. Debugging is an art, and it'll be the best way to get somewhere.

Comment: @Shah you've done it mostly in the MySQLi Object Oriented Way, if you want to do it in the Object Oriented way, learn the prepared statements. Or if you wanna work like mysql to mysqli_* then just use mysqli_ every time instead of mysql, but mysqli_connect() is not similar to mysql_connect()

Comment: @Shah try the code I gave you as an answer. :)

Comment: @Hassan I've tried your code.. its not give any error at all. But instead it just show "No search results found!" everytime i search my for keywords. As you said above, except for mysql_connect() can I work my like mysql everytime I write mysqli?

Comment: Yes, you can work like mysql_* by just making it mysqli but you connect to mysqli by:

$con = mysqli_connect('host', 'user', 'password', 'db');

But in mysql you also do mysql_select_db.

Comment: ic.. if I can use mysqli_* like old mysql_*. I think I wont have much trouble. I become confused when mysql_* become mysqli->blabla with lot of change plus new thing like 'prepare' that I've never seen. By the way, thanks a lot sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put the "?" in the query, that's how you do a "prepared statement". But, (a) the mysqli->query function does not do prepared statements, it's does plain old one-shot statements. And (b) even if it did, you never bind a value to the "?". So you are searching for records where keywords equals a literal question mark.

You can do the query just like you did it with old MySQL, building the parameters in as a string:

```
$find_posts = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `search_table`
  WHERE keywords like '%$search_posts%'");
```

Or you could do it as a prepared statement:

```
$pq =$mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `search_table`
  WHERE keywords like ?");
$pq->bind_param('i', '%' . $search_posts . '%');
$pq->execute();
$find_posts=$pq->get_result();
```

Also note that changing the test from LIKE to = is going to change your results. You probably don't want to do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. I've tried both of your suggestion. But only the first one work for me. About the prepared statement, I have tried everything related to prepared statement from youtube, tutorials, lot of videos and do exactly like in those but never able to make it work. I'm don't know why but I'm feel better now because it takes me 10 days to do this thing. And thanks again sir ^_^

Comment: Well, hmm, without further info I can't say why your prepared statement didn't work. If you want to pursue it you could post your latest attempt at the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have done it wrong! The MySQLi Code:

```
$search_posts = $_POST['search_posts'];
$find_posts = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT title, keywords FROM search_table WHERE keywords=?");
$find_posts->bind_param('s', $search_posts);
$find_posts->execute();
$find_posts->bind_result($title, $keywords);
$find_posts->store_result();
if($find_posts->num_rows > 0) {
    while($find_posts->fetch()) {
        echo "<a href='#'>$title</a> >>> $keywords<br />"; 
    }
} else {
    echo "No search results found!";
}
$find_posts->free_result();
$find_posts->close();
```

Comment: If you are familiar with mysqli, you would have known it already. If not... why answer at all?

Comment: Agreed, it's a prepared statement so it's not needed, I'll just update his post.

Comment: @YourCommonSense all you do in everyone's thread is find faults, ever willing to give solutions to anyone?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with finding faults. There are so many people willing to give a "solution" (or, rather, to snach some rep points, as they don't care if their solution good or bad or even if it working at all) that only one person finding faults wont't do any harm.

Comment: @YourCommonSense can you please explain to me about it or provide better solution code? Because i'm not familiar with mysql or mysqli. I've tried to put prepare but it give me an error so I remove it because don't know how to set it (prepare)

Comment: @Hassan - I've noticed two things: You may have to wait to set `$search_posts` until after you've bound the parameter, and your check for `if($title > 0)` should be checking for `$find_posts->num_rows` instead.

Comment: @Shah this is not a tutorial site. If you want to learn mysqli from scratch you have to buy yourself a book, google for the online tutorial or a video. And then spend some time learning it to be able to write desired code yourself. This site is not supposed for writing code for you. **Especially by someone who has even less experience than you**

Comment: oh yh, i was confused, i'll fix it.

Comment: @YourCommonSense you are trying say that I have lesser experience than him?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm currently learning it (by try and error). I watched lots of tutorials and videos. So I made mysql attached above even I dont know much about it. Did you see I said in a nice way "can you please explain to me". At least for Hassan, he tried to correct my fault code. How about you? Is this all you can do? >>>"This site is not supposed for writing code for you".

Comment: @Shah nope, it is not all I can do. In fact, I answer many *good* questions. And I don't understand what have to be explained.

Comment: @YourCommonSense if you have answer many good questions, then its good for you but I'm so sorry if my question is not as good as that. I'm a learner and i hope to get answer for my question. Because this is why this site is made of. And if if you dont understand what have to be explained, my assumptions is either you are thinking yourself as a pro(arrogant type) who refuse to to answer basic question from new learner or you have even lesser experience than me. ^_^

Comment: @Shah may be you are right or may be it's just you are unable to express what have to be explained to you.